# r - creating a matrix of bivariate frequencies

Tags: r, matrix, frequency

Suppose I have a matrix where the rows represent individual samples. I'm sampling without replacement so rows won't contain duplicated entries.

```
samp_frame <- 1:6
samp <- matrix(c(1,2,3,3,4,1,5,1,6),nrow=3,ncol=3)
samp

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    1
[3,]    3    1    6
```

I want to compute the number of samples which contain a pair of values then store the results in a matrix. For example, entry (1,2) in the output matrix would be the number of times the values 1 and 2 appeared together in the same row. Using the example from above, we would get:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    1    2    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    1    0    0
[3,]    2    0    2    0    1    1
[4,]    1    1    0    1    0    0
[5,]    1    0    1    0    1    0
[6,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
```

I wrote a function to do this, but it's probably not very efficient. So I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve it.

```
pair_freq <- function(samp_frame,samp){

   N <- length(samp_frame)
   output <- matrix(0,nrow=N,ncol=N)

   # Fill in diagonal entries
   temp <- table(samp)
   freq <- data.frame(id=as.numeric(rownames(temp)), 
                      count=data.frame(temp)[,2])
   for (i in 1:N){
      output[i,i] <- freq[i,"count"]
   }

   # Fill in off-diagonal entries
   for(i in 1:nrow(samp)){
      current <- unique(samp[i,])
      for (j in 1:(N-1)){
         m <- j+1
         for (k in m:N){
            output[j,k] <- output[j,k] + all(c(j,k) %in% current)
            output[k,j] <- output[j,k]
         }
      }
   }
   output
}
```

I'm also open to the idea of displaying the frequencies in the following format if it's faster to do.

```
X1 X2 freq
 1  1    3
 1  2    1
 1  3    2
 1  4    1
 1  5    1
 1  6    1
 2  2    1
 2  3    1
...
```

Comment: How many columns does you real matrix contain? Can you explain how duplicate numbers on a same row are handled? For example, what would be the contributions of a row `c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2)` to `out[1, 1], out[1, 2], out[2, 2]`?

Comment: @flodel That's a good point. I'm sampling without replacement so there won't be any duplicate elements in the same row. At the moment, my real data matrix has up to 20 columns (each sample/row has 20 values). I should probably also mention that I'm sampling numbers from 1 to 25.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
is.present <- function(j)apply(samp,1,function(row)as.integer(any(row==j)))
m <- sapply(min(samp):max(samp),is.present)
t(m) %*% m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    3    1    2    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    0    1    0    0
# [3,]    2    0    2    0    1    1
# [4,]    1    1    0    1    0    0
# [5,]    1    0    1    0    1    0
# [6,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
```

So you have n samples (3 in your example) with k possible outcomes (1:6 in your example).

In this approach, `is.present(j)` creates a vector of length `n` which element is 1 if the number `j` is present in that row, 0 otherwise. Then

```
m <- sapply(min(samp):max(samp),is.present)
```

creates an n × k matrix `m` which has one row for each row in samp, and one column for each possible outcome, with `m[i,j] = 1` if the the number `j` is present in row `i` of samp. Then,

> m<sup>T</sup> × m

produces a k × k matrix which element `[i,j]` is the number or rows in `samp` where `i` and `j` appear together.

Comment: That's a very clever approach! Thank you for providing a very clear explanation.